# Creating tick box in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create such kind of thing in Flutter with possibility of putting a tick?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZASh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use widget called `CheckBox` and use `shape` property to make it round

```
Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
      value: isChecked,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
```

[here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) you can check more about `Checkbox`

Comment: @petrashin_nikita mark as tick if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is called a `Checkbox`, and like most things, Flutter has a `Widget` for that.

It's called `Checkbox` and the Flutter Team has a full live example of how it's used, go to their [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) to find out more!